# this void function is not working ;(

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun();

void main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<0; i++) fun();
}    

void fun()
{
    static int cnt = 0;
    cnt++;
    printf("count is %d\n", cnt);
}
```

and this merely prints blank ;(
What's wrong with my code?

I debugged and it showed no bugs here.

Comment: i < 0 on your for loop. This basically means "Do nothing"

Comment: Also, you're overloading the function `fun()` which is not permitted in pure-C

Comment: "it showed no bugs". It would be advisable never to make such a claim so lightly. That's one lesson all experienced programmers would know about.

Comment: Is declaring a prototype considered such a thing? Still, declaring functions after main seems a bit wrong to me...

Comment: @BassemDy There is no overloading in this code

Comment: @MattMcNabb my bad, was not familiar with function prototyping in c before..

Comment: @BassemDy this actually isn't a prototype, it's a function declaration. Prototypes have to have an argument list (possibly `(void)`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb why declare `fun()` twice though? What is this called? I don't recall the need to declare a function twice..

Comment: @BassemDy functions cannot be called before they have been declared

Answer (score 5):

Your `for` loop is wrong. It will only loop if `i` is less than 0 but since `i` is 0 it never does.

A way to fix it would be changing the upper bound of the loop like:

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++) fun(); // Calls fun 20 times
```

Answer (score 3):

You are running your loop with the condition

```
i < 0
```

i is initialized as 0. So it is never less than 0.

Change this to:

```
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) fun();
```

And it should run 10 times.

Comment: It should, or it will?

Comment: Well I'm not going to make the assumption that nothing else is going to get broken in the process :)

Answer (score 3):

the problem is at `for (i=0; i<0; i++) fun();` `i<0` means that the loop exits when `i<0` is false. So, the code just exits without executing the `fun()`